# xcode 7.3.1 not show controller in debug view hierarchy

Tags: xcode, xcode7.3

I want to inspect drawing of the views, I press debug view hierarchy, but the screen is empty

More precisely, doesn't show only one controller, that is the screen with one controller, other controllers normally draws. It is CollectionViewController and if in a code to put quantity of cells 0, then the controller is displayed in full

Comment: Please file a radar at bugreport.apple.com